# Why KeyError while plottin a pandas data frame with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, ipython

I have this data frame:

```
       date_obj      col1     col2       col3      col4
40038  2012-11-19   1.000   0.831856   0.986209   0.843919
40039  2012-11-20   2.015   0.521764   1.177320   0.938245
40040  2012-11-21   1.160   1.645345   1.964620   4.536440
40041  2012-11-22   3.171   2.444018   2.931550   3.737840
40042  2012-11-23   4.563   3.208111   3.587250   2.434040
40043  2012-11-24   5.379   3.863732   3.824540   1.634780
40044  2012-11-26   1.125  20.756739   4.162820  23.552100
40045  2012-11-27   3.340   5.369354   4.535090   1.129290
40046  2012-11-28   5.463  12.185730   8.102790   1.224300
40047  2012-11-29   6.596  14.328685   9.271000  24.655600
40048  2012-11-30  31.544  13.513497  12.103400  21.273500
40049  2012-12-01  24.921  26.144050  16.256200  13.883100
40050  2012-12-03   5.488   2.581351   7.220790   3.349450
40051  2012-12-04   6.977   5.893819   5.548870   2.948770
40052  2012-12-05   7.115   6.533022   5.863820   2.517030
40053  2012-12-06   5.842   8.754232   7.518660   1.447940
40054  2012-12-07   6.346  12.018631  10.263100  11.837400
40055  2012-12-08  17.666   4.548846  10.610400  11.110800
40056  2012-12-10   4.300   2.823566   1.475000   1.989210
40057  2012-12-11   2.415   2.436319   2.677440   2.908270
40058  2012-12-12   2.319   2.121092   3.455550   3.890480
40059  2012-12-13   1.000   1.633918   3.858540   4.316940
40060  2012-12-14   2.238   1.688475   5.065990   5.267850
40061  2012-12-15   1.798   2.621267   7.175370   6.957340
```

I try to plot it in the following way:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(17, 10))
plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=45)
plt.plot_date(df_cut['date_obj'],df_cut['col1'], color='black', linestyle='-', markersize=3, linewidth=2)
plt.plot_date(df_cut['date_obj'],df_cut['col2'], color='red', linestyle='-', markersize=3)
plt.plot_date(df_cut['date_obj'],df_cut['col3'], color='green', linestyle='-', markersize=3)
plt.plot_date(df_cut['date_obj'],df_cut['col4'], color='blue', linestyle='-', markersize=3)
```

As a result I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-544-1b8650d1e7e7> in <module>()
/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in plot_date(x, y, fmt, tz, xdate, ydate, hold, **kwargs)
   2850     try:
   2851         ret = ax.plot_date(x, y, fmt=fmt, tz=tz, xdate=xdate, ydate=ydate,
-> 2852                            **kwargs)
   2853         draw_if_interactive()
   2854     finally:
ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in plot_date(self, x, y, fmt, tz, xdate, ydate, **kwargs)
   4061         if not self._hold: self.cla()
   4062 
-> 4063         ret = self.plot(x, y, fmt, **kwargs)
   4064 
   4065         if xdate:
ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3994         lines = []
   3995 
-> 3996         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   3997             self.add_line(line)
   3998             lines.append(line)
ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    328                 return
    329             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 330                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    331                     yield seg
    332                 return
ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    306             x = np.arange(y.shape[0], dtype=float)
    307 
--> 308         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    309 
    310         if self.command == 'plot':
python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    222     def _xy_from_xy(self, x, y):
    223         if self.axes.xaxis is not None and self.axes.yaxis is not None:
--> 224             bx = self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
    225             by = self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    226 
ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in update_units(self, data)
   1299         neednew = self.converter != converter
   1300         self.converter = converter
-> 1301         default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
   1302         #print 'update units: default=%s, units=%s'%(default, self.units)
   1303         if default is not None and self.units is None:
ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.pyc in default_units(x, axis)
   1156         'Return the tzinfo instance of *x* or of its first element, or None'
   1157         try:
-> 1158             x = x[0]
   1159         except (TypeError, IndexError):
   1160             pass
ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    611     def __getitem__(self, key):
    612         try:
--> 613             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
    614         except InvalidIndexError:
    615             pass
ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
    761         """
    762         try:
--> 763             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    764         except KeyError, e1:
    765             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':
```

What is strange, this code works for some data frames and for some it doesn't. The data frames are not different by their structure. The only difference between them is only in values that they contain.

Could anybody please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi ! You copy-pasted a lot of stuff but not the interesting ong. Your backtrace is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataframe store dates as numpy.datetime64 objects, not python datetime objects.

Furthermore matplotlib.plot_date uses its own numeric representation of dates.

You could draw your data this way:

```
plt.plot_date(matplotlib.dates.date2num(pandas.to_datetime(df_cut['date_obj'].values)),df_cut['col1'].values, color='black', linestyle='-', markersize=3, linewidth=2)
```

Or you could define column 'date_obj' as the index of your data:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(YourDataSource, columns=['date_obj','col1','col2','col3','col4'],index='date_obj')
```

And then simply use pandas' plot() attribute:

```
df0['col1'].plot()
```